# How to open url in php without redirect

Tags: php

I need some help with PHP, I want to open the url to get the full output from get-listing.php.

I tried this:

```
<?php
  $url = file_get_contents("http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php");
  echo $url;
?>
```

It will show me an empty page, but if I use this:

```
<?php
  header('Location: http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php');
?>
```

It will redirect me to the get-listing.php which I will get the full output.

If I open the get-listing.php url, I will see the full output which will look like this:

```
101 ABC FAMILY

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=ABC FAMILY&id=101

Stream 1
102 CBS

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=CBS&id=102

Stream 1
103 CNN USA

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=CNN USA&id=103

Stream 1
105 ESPN USA

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=ESPN USA&id=105

Stream 1
106 FOX News

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=FOX News&id=106

Stream 1
107 Animal Planet

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=Animal Planet&id=107

Stream 1
108 USA Network

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=USA Network&id=108

Stream 1
110 SPIKE

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=SPIKE&id=110

Stream 1
111 BRAVO USA

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=BRAVO USA&id=111

Stream 1
112 BRAVO1

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=BRAVO1&id=112

Stream 1
113 BRAVO2

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=BRAVO2&id=113

Stream 1
114 BRAVO3

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=BRAVO3&id=114

Stream 1
115 BRAVO4

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=BRAVO4&id=115

Stream 1
116 BRAVO5

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=BRAVO5&id=116

Stream 1
117 BRAVO6

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=BRAVO6&id=117

Stream 1
118 BRAVO7

http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php?channels=BRAVO7&id=118

Stream 1
```

How do I open the url in my PHP page to get the full output without redirect?

Comment: do you want to get entire code in that page?

Comment: The web server is probably rejecting the request because it requires a User Agent header. `file_get_contents()` doesn't set a default User Agent. Try using cURL with a User Agent set.

Comment: @ feroz akbar yeah and the full output please.

Comment: @user3208332 is your PHP implementation set to both show errors and allow file_get_contents to get remove files?  If you can't check your php.ini, it may behoove you to try a cURL based solution https://php.net/curl

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving  contents from url using file_get_contents ,allow_url_fopen setting 
should be configured to On in php.ini

Comment: I don't have the php.ini, what i need to do?

Comment: First verify the setting using phpinfo() .Also as an alternate solution you can try using curl to read content from url but curl extension should be enabled in php.ini

Comment: For modifying configuration setting in php.ini you can contact server hosting provider

Answer (score -1):

use this class from here  [httpclient](http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/)

it is easy to use

```
include("HttpClient.class.php");

$client = new HttpClient('testbox.elementfx.com');

$data=$client->get('http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php')

$fulldata=$client->getContent();
```

or include using `include()`

like this

```
include ("http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php"); (not recommended security issues)
```

Look at your `php.ini` and make sure `allow_url_include` is set to 1. Restart HTTPD, done.

Comment: 1) Using an include like that is incredibly dangerous

2) Why recommend a lib when cURL comes in the base library

3) Doesn't help the poster understand what's going on with his code.

Comment: thats why i mentioned as not recommended in my answer. And to include remote URLs this is the ONLY WAY in php.

Comment: @ferozakbar thanks for this, how I can find the php.ini? I tried to look for it but i can't find it. I have got an error Fatal error: Class 'HttpClient' not found in /home/myuser/public_html/myscript.php on line 2

Comment: you have to download the httpcilent.class.php file from the link i have mentioned in my answer. And copy that file in the same directory where file is present

Comment: @ferozakbar thanks, I have download the httpcilent.class.php file from the link you have mentioned, but when I open the get-listing.php, the output are still showing as empty. Any idea?

Comment: you need to use $client->getContent()

Comment: if this didnt work then please update your answer with what have you modified in your code

Answer (score -1):

You would be best off using cURL

```
$url="http://adfoc.us/1575051";

$ch = curl_init();

$header=array('GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1',
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'Host:adfoc.us',
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36',
    );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies.txt');

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```